# Is there a a "back to the top" in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm kind of noob in ruby programming. My question is if there's something like anchors  or goto in ruby, so I can create loops inside Ifs... Is there something like that?

**Example:**

```
anchorX
gets variable
if variable == "option one"
   puts "you choose right"
else
   puts "you choose wrong! DO IT AGAIN!"
go to anchorX
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Ruby does not have `goto`. Try a loop instead:

```
loop {
    input = gets.chomp
    if input == "option one"
        puts "you choose right"
        break
    else
        puts "you choose wrong! DO IT AGAIN!"
    end
}
```

Or, an alternative method (and arguably slightly more readable):

```
input = gets.chomp
until input == "option one"
   puts "you choose wrong! DO IT AGAIN!"
   input = gets.chomp
end
puts "you choose right"
```

Comment: +1 for "until". Very ruby-esque

Comment: Yeah, but the `until` version requires duplicating the `gets`.  I prefer the `loop` version (although I would use `do`...`end` instead of curlies).

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to use `goto` for something so trivial?

Use a `while` loop.  The `while` syntax for ruby is:

```
while [condition] do
   (put your code here)
end
```

For example:

```
gets variable
while variable != "option one" do
    puts "you choose wrong!"
    gets variable
puts "you choose right"
```

Comment: the Idea is not to repeat myself in a text only game... for example...  the player can went back and redo the steps if he forgot something.
A example would be: theres a table with a key and a door. If user writes go to door, there's a logic test varmovement =="pick key" he moves foward to the next if... elsif "open door" puts "the door is locked, do you need a key for that" and move the user back to the start of the conditional

Answer (score 0):

Besides loop statements, you can use `retry` statement to repeat entire *begin/end* block.

```
begin
    input = gets.chomp
    if input == "option one"
        puts "you choose right"
    else
        puts "you choose wrong! DO IT AGAIN!"
        raise
    end
rescue 
    retry
end
```